# Complicated implicit plotting

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization

I'm quite new to Mathematica and have already spent tons of time on problems of this type, browsing through tutorials and topics here. I'm now coming to conclusion that it cannot be done and am about to give up working on it, so I just thought I would ask here as a last resort.

I am working with the following two horrible expressions (looks bad but copied straight from Mathematica with LATEXing option):

$\qquad 
\frac{2 \left(3 a^2+3 a\, \text{alpha}\, \text{t1}+\text{alpha}^2 \text{t1}^2\right)}{\text{t1}^3}+\frac{2 \left(3 b^2-3 b\, \text{beta}\, \text{t2}+\text{beta}^2 \text{t2}^2\right)}{\text{t2}^3}-\text{tau}\, (-\text{t1}-\text{t2}+1)
$

and

$\qquad 
2 \left(3 a^2+3 a\, (\text{alpha}-2 b+\text{beta})+\text{alpha}^2+\text{alpha}\, (\text{beta}-3 b)+3 b^2-3 b\, \text{beta}+\text{beta}^2\right)
$

I would like to compare the two. In particular, in the first expression I would like to choose `t1` and `t2` optimally so that the whole thing is minimised, subject to `0 < t1`, `0 < t2`, `0 < t1 + t2 < 1`. Then fix `tau`, `b` and `beta` at some values, say `b = beta = 0.1` and `tau = 2` and equate the two, so that in the end we have an expressions of the form `F(a, alpha) = 0`. And now, I would like to plot the corresponding curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$. One obstacle is choosing `t1` and `t2` correctly, as working with stationary points is fairly hard/tedious. The other obstacle is the implicit plotting itself. In slightly easier version of this problem I do get correct plots with `ContourPlot` with increased `PlotPoints`, but here not really.

Note that if in particular we choose some `a` then solving for `alpha` is trivial, so perhaps some numerical approach could be used? All I need is a decent looking plot with the curves.

As I said I have tried numerous approaches, but I'm by no means an expert, so I was wondering if anyone had any hints. I've already come to terms with the fact that this is not doable, but perhaps I'm wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the first expression:

```
(2 (3 a^2 + 3 a alpha t1 + alpha^2 t1^2))/t1^3 + 
  (2 (3 b^2 - 3 b beta t2 + beta^2 t2^2))/t2^3 - (1 - t1 - t2) tau
```

Here is the second:

```
2 (3 a^2 + alpha^2 + 3 b^2 - 3 b beta + beta^2 + alpha (-3 b + beta) + 
     3a (alpha - 2 b + beta))
```

Comment: Minimizing the first expression can be done by `Minimize[{(2 (3 a^2 + 3 a alpha t1 + alpha^2 t1^2))/t1^3 + (2 (3 b^2 - 3 b beta t2 + beta^2 t2^2))/t2^3 - (1 - t1 - t2) tau, 0 < t1 + t2 < 1}, {t1, t2}]`, which seems to take a long time to evaluate.

Comment: @JHM I tried that, but the evaluation never completed on MMA 10.4.0 Have you had better luck?

Comment: @MarcoB Nope, I aborted the evaluation after letting it run for about 15 minutes. I use Mathematica 10.3.1.

Comment: Yea, I've tried that but to no avail. A bit of analysis reveals that depending on signs of $(a,alpha,b,beta)$ the stationary points will be minima, but there's 16 of them and juggling them and changing signs and with the additional constraint $(t1+t2) \in (0,1)$ on top of that is pretty cruel and it is rather hard to get a grip on what's going on really

Comment: I've just realised there is one more constraint: both $t1$ and $t2$ need to be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just do the minimization numerically.

```
f[a_, alpha_, b_, beta_, tau_, t1_, t2_] := 
 (2 (3 a^2 + 3 a alpha t1 + alpha^2 t1^2))/t1^3 
 + (2 (3 b^2 - 3 b beta t2 + beta^2 t2^2))/t2^3 
 - (1 - t1 - t2) tau
fmin[a_, alpha_, b_, beta_, tau_] := 
 NMinValue[{f[a, alpha, b, beta, tau, t1, t2], 
   t1 >= 0 && t2 >= 0 && t1 + t2 <= 1}, {t1, t2}]
g[a_, alpha_, b_, beta_, tau_] := 
 2 (3 a^2 + alpha^2 + 3 b^2 - 3 b beta + beta^2 + 
    alpha (-3 b + beta) + 3 a (alpha - 2 b + beta))

With[{b = 0.1, beta = 0.1, tau = 2}, 
 ContourPlot[
  fmin[a, alpha, b, beta, tau] == g[a, alpha, b, beta, tau], 
  {a, -1, 1}, {alpha, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> False]]
```

[image]

However this takes quite a long time.